# Help with understanding the concept of paracompactness.

Tags: general-topology

The definition for *paracompactness* that I'm given is as follows:

"A set $U\subseteq\epsilon$ is paracompact with respect to the topology ($\epsilon$,$\tau$) if and only if every open cover {$O_i$} of $U$ has a locally finite refinement."

However I am having a hard time understanding what *locally finite refinement* means. I've looked on wikipedia and various other websites but it doesn't seem to do it for me. Could anyone please explain *paracompactness* in a simple sort of fashion with emphasis of the definition of *locally finite refinement*?

Examples and graphs could also help - Cheers :)

Answer (score 7):

Note first that the definition of *compactness* [sic] can be viewed as an adversarial game: You start with a set $K$ in some topological space. Your opponent picks an arbitrary family of open sets whose union contains $K$. Your task is to "discard" all but finitely many of your opponent's sets in a way that the remaining sets still cover $K$. To say $K$ is *compact* is to say "you have a winning strategy against a perfect opponent".

*Paracompactness* can be give a similar interpretation. You start with a set $U$ in some topological space. Your opponent picks an arbitrary family of open sets whose union contains $U$. Your task is a bit more elaborate than before:

- You're allowed to "shrink" the sets your opponent gives you, i.e., to replace any open set by an open subset ("refinement").
- The subsets you pick sets must cover $U$, but every point of $U$ must have a neighborhood *meeting only finitely many* of your sets ("locally finite").

To say $U$ is "paracompact" means you have a winning strategy against a perfect opponent.

Answer (score 2):

An open cover $\{U_i\}$ is a refinement of an open cover $\{V_j\}$ if for each $i$ there exists a $j$ with $U_i \subseteq V_j$.

An open cover $\{U_i\}$ of $X$ is locally finite, if for every $x\in X$, there exists an open neighborhood of $x$ which only intersects finitely many of the $\{U_i\}$.